# What is wrong with this code? I tried to make ads show every 5 rounds but it doesn't work

Tags: unity-game-engine, ads

I have this script where I want the ads to show every 5 rounds/losses. When I test the game the ads just don't show. They only show when I put 1 in the gamesToShowAd variable. I have tried multiple ways how to make ads play every 5 rounds/losses and none of them worked.
GameManager script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject gameOverCanvas;
    public AdsManager ads;
    int gameCount = 0;
    int gamesToShowAd = 5;

    private void Start()
    {
        Time.timeScale = 1;
        ads.ShowBanner();
        gameCount = 0;
    }

    public void GameOver()
    {
        gameOverCanvas.SetActive(true);
        Time.timeScale = 0;

        gameCount++; //increment game count

        if (gameCount >= gamesToShowAd) // check if player played enough games to show ad
        {
            ads.PlayAd();
            gameCount = 0; // reset counter
        }
    }

    public void Replay()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(0);
    }

}
```

Maybe its something to do with the ads manager script?
AdsManager:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Advertisements;

public class AdsManager : MonoBehaviour, IUnityAdsListener
{
#if UNITY_IOS
    string gameId = "#######";
#else
    string gameId = "#######";
#endif

    Action onRewardedAdSuccess;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Advertisement.Initialize(gameId);
        Advertisement.AddListener(this);
        ShowBanner();
    }

    public void PlayAd()
    {
        if(Advertisement.IsReady("Interstitial_Android"))
            Advertisement.Show("Interstitial_Android");
    }

    public void PlayRewardedAd(Action onSuccess)
    {
        onRewardedAdSuccess = onSuccess;
        if(Advertisement.IsReady("Rewarded_Android"))
        {
        Advertisement.Show("Rewarded_Android");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Rewarded ad is not ready!");
        }
    }

    public void ShowBanner()
    {
        if (Advertisement.IsReady("Banner_Android"))
        {
            Advertisement.Banner.SetPosition(BannerPosition.BOTTOM_CENTER);
            Advertisement.Banner.Show("Banner_Android");
        }
        else
        {
            StartCoroutine(RepeatShowBanner());
        }
    }

    public void HideBanner()
    {
        Advertisement.Banner.Hide();
    }

    IEnumerator RepeatShowBanner()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
        ShowBanner();
    }

    public void OnUnityAdsReady(string placementId)
    {
        Debug.Log("ADS ARE READY!");
    }

    public void OnUnityAdsDidError(string message)
    {
        Debug.Log("ERROR: " + message);
    }

    public void OnUnityAdsDidStart(string placementId)
    {
        Debug.Log("VIDEO STARTED!");
    }

    public void OnUnityAdsDidFinish(string placementId, ShowResult showResult)
    {
        if (placementId == "Rewarded_Android" && showResult == ShowResult.Finished)
        {
            onRewardedAdSuccess.Invoke();
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Your replay will be resetting up all these variables as they aren’t destroyonload. So it will always be the first death

Comment: Do I really need to put DestroyOnLoad? I only know DontDestroyOnLoad. Where do I need to put the destroyonload?

Comment: Have you ever tried typing code on a phone? It really loves to change everything. 

Yes. You need dontdestroyonload or a static class available throughout the game. Choice is yours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of 5 rounds, why don't you make it 20% chance of playing every round? This is more efficient than your way.

But your issue seems to be here. (Unity calls **Start()** and **Awake()** every time the scene that the object is from is called)
Take a look at [this](https://answers.unity.com/questions/662263/dontdestroyonload-calls-awake-and-start-function-e.html).

```
private void Start(){
    Time.timeScale = 1;
    ads.ShowBanner();
    gameCount = 0;
    //It sets to 0 every time your scene reloads
    //Try creating this object at your main menu or loading a empty scene before hitting play on menu
}
```

Or if you want that percentage to show ads, create this:

```
[Range(0, 10)]
public int chanceToShowAds;
private int currentChance;
    
public void GameOver(){
    
    currentChance = Random.Range(0, 10);
    
    if (currentChance >= chanceToShowAds)
        ads.PlayAd();
}
```

Comment: If I do it the percentage way, do I need to write the DontDestroyOnLoad part? Because when I do it without the DontDestroyOnLoad it still plays an ad every round.

Comment: You don't need to use **DontDestroyOnLoad**... I do the same percentage-thing at my game and it's not required.

Comment: And my mistake here... It should be **currentChance <= chanceToShowAds**

Comment: Thanks! This really is a better way to make the ads appear after a random number of rounds. This really helped me.